# d3.js on click zoom function not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to zoom in on different points on a map based on a click event.

This is the code I have:

```
var centered;
var x;
var y;
var zoomLevel;

var zoomSettings = {
    duration: 1000,
    ease: d3.easeCubicOut,
    zoomLevel: 10
};


svg.selectAll("path")
   .data(json_data.features)
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("d", path)
   .attr("cursor","pointer")
   .style('stroke', '#FFA183')
   .style('stroke-width', '1')
   .on("click", function (d) {
      if(d && centered !== d) {
         var centroid = path.centroid(d);

         x = centroid[0];
         y = centroid[1];
         zoomLevel = zoomSettings.zoomLevel;
         centered = d;
     } else {
         x = w/2;
         y= h/2;

         zoomLevel = 1;
         centered = null;
        }  
    });
```

I have looked at a number of answers on stack overflow but none of them seem to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only calculating the translate and scale values. You want to also apply the new transformation values onto the svg paths:

```
svg.selectAll("path").attr("transform", "translate(" +  w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")scale(" + zoomLevel + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")").style("stroke-width", 1.5 / zoomLevel + "px");
```

Ideally, all paths are grouped in the svg and the transform is applied to the group. Please check Mike Bostock's example here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590

Hope this helps!